# @WebFilter(urlPatterns) not mapping HTTP request properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a function with `@GetMapping(value = "/getToken")` that writes JSON content.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getToken")
public String getToken(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    // jsonObject
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(jsonObject);
}
```

Now, a user can make a `GET` request to above mapping using a URL like this:

> `localhost:8080/getToken?username="username"&password="password"`

I have also created a class called `CORSFilter` that implements `javax.servlet.Filter` and i want this filter to intercept only those request that have `/getToken` in the request path.

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/getToken")
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // validate user and password
        chain.doFilter(requestToUse, responseToUse);
    }
}
```

Now, when I hit `localhost:8080` or `localhost:8080/thankyou` in the browser then the above filter is getting called.

How can I stop this?

I want to call above filter only if the URL path is

> `localhost:8080/getToken?username="user"&password="pass"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, Spring Boot doesn't honor the urlPatterns for filters declared with WebFilter. If you need to apply a pattern, you'll have to declare the filter as a bean and declare a filter registration for that bean, in a configuration class. For example:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<CORSFilter> corsFilterRegistration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<CORSFilter> filterRegistrationBean =
        new FilterRegistrationBean<>(corsFilter());
    filterRegistrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Collections.singleton("/getToken"));
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}

@Bean
public CORSFilter corsFilter() {
    return new CORSFilter();
}
```

Note however that Spring Boot has [native support for CORS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-cors). You don't need any filter for that.

Comment: Will it work for non-spring boot applications as well ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use interceptors- [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html). Please refer below url for how-to.

https://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptor-example-handlerinterceptor-handlerinterceptoradapter

Answer (score 0):

If it is pure jsp based application then you need to declare it in web.xml because **@WebFilter** doesn't guarantee the order of execution of filters or if it is spring based application then you can use **@CrossOrigin** on method level or declare a bean to filter each and every url as mentioned in the below url

[Spring CORS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)